# Как в Vue.js создать много new Object в v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Друзья, у меня есть компонент `PlainDraggable` (https://anseki.github.io/plain-draggable/), создаю его в DOM так:

```
<div id="draggable">Drag This</div>
```

потом в JS выполняю

```
new PlainDraggable(document.getElementById('draggable'));
```

Надо сделать несколько фигур, решил создать в Vue.js, в цикле. v-for:

```
    <div id="app">
        <div v-for="(item, index) in my_items" 
        :id='`draggable${item.id}`' 
        class="draggable" {{item.id}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

DOM создаётся, а как реализовать строку

```
new PlainDraggable(document.getElementById('draggableXXX'));
```

Ничего не получается. В `updated() {}` наверное надо цикл вставить, и создать все мои объекты `PlainDraggable`, но как это реализовать?
 Заранее премного благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    console.log(document.getElementById(name));
  }
}

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `<div>
    <div v-for="(name, index) in names" 
      :id='name' 
      >{{createPerson(name)}} {{name}}</div> 
    </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      names: ['Jhon', 'Mike', 'Kate']
    };
  },
  methods: {
    createPerson(name) {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        new Person(name);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<div id="app">  </div>
```

Comment: наверное ответ был бы ещё более полезен, имея минимальные комментарии кода